# Reset weights of a pretrained incetion_v3 model in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a pretrained inception_v3 model and I use this function to load the frozen weights

```
tf.import_graph_def(graph_def)
```

For my task, I also want to change/reset the weights of this inception_v3 model.

I am able to get all the variables by

```
op = sess.graph.get_operations()
```

On the other hand, I want only those variables which have the weights. In this case, `tf.trainable_variables()` returns a `None`.

tl;dr: I want to extract weight and bias variables from a frozen graph

Comment: Is there something wrong with `[a for a in ckpt.get_variable_to_shape_map().keys() if 'weights' in a or 'bias' in a]`? Everything else looks BatchNorm-related.